# How to change the font in matlibplot in python?

Tags: python, graph, fonts

For example, how can I set the font type as 'arial' or 'times and new roman'. Thank you.

Comment: You can consider this stackoverflow example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321670/how-to-change-fonts-in-matplotlib-python

Comment: Refer this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23572192/2956066