# How do I change the font family of matplotlib bar chart labels?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, bar-chart, font-family

I'm using the following line to add labels to the bar chart, how can I adjust the font family?

```
plt.xticks(xticks_pos, labels,  ha='right', rotation=55, fontsize=20)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use fontname as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321670/how-to-change-fonts-in-matplotlib-python).

```
plt.xticks(xticks_pos, labels,  ha='right', rotation=55, fontsize=20, fontname='monospace')
```