# How to change the font family of matplotlib legend AND legend title?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, legend-properties

I would like to use the font family "Consolas" in my matplotlib legend in order to benefit the monospaced font. I also want a legend title.

But it seems that when I change the font family of my legend, it erase the legend title.

Here is a code to see the problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 10), np.linspace(0, 1), label='First plot     #1')
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 10), np.linspace(0, 2), label='Second plot    #2')
plt.legend(loc='best', title="My Awesome Legend Title")
```

[image]

```
# I would like to use a Monospaced font so I have found this snippet to do so
plt.setp(ax.legend().texts, family='Consolas')
# But as you can see, my legend title just disapeared !!!
```

[image]

```
# how can I do ?
# Can I force again the legend title ?
ax.legend(title="My NEW Awesome Legend Title")
# Yes ! But it changes the font family again to default.
```

[image]

Do you have any solution ?
Thanks for your help and precious time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change fonts in matplotlib (python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321670/how-to-change-fonts-in-matplotlib-python)  Spefically use rcParams to set the global font as per the second answer

Comment: I haven't succeed yet using rcParams but my matplotlib and python knowledge is limited. I also use many figures in my codes and want the "Consolas" font family only on few of legend and not everywhere (xlabel etc.)

Comment: [You can change rcParams temporarily](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#temporary-rc-settings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple points:

- The title of the legend disappears as soon as I execute `ax.legend()`, so the disappearance is not actually caused by setting the font.  This simply creates a new legend, with no title.
- The legend title and legend texts are separate items.

This worked for me:

```
leg = ax.get_legend()
plt.setp(leg.get_title(), family='Ubuntu Mono')
plt.setp(leg.get_texts(), family='Ubuntu Mono')
```

(`Consolas` is not one of the fonts available on my system.)

Comment: Works perfectly for me too. It solves the problem efficiently and explains why. Thanks for sharing your experience. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While @Warren Weckesser's answer works, I thought I'd point out that this can be achieved directly in `ax.legend()` with the `prop` and `title_fontproperties` keywords:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.linspace(0, 10), np.linspace(0, 1), label='First plot     #1')
ax.plot(np.linspace(0, 10), np.linspace(0, 2), label='Second plot    #2')
ax.legend(loc='best', title="My Awesome Legend Title",
          prop=dict(family='monospace'),
          title_fontproperties=dict(family='monospace'))
```

[image: changing legend font family to monospace]

---

Side note: If you are using the monospace font only to align "#1" and "#2" then you might be able to achieve this with latex, without the need for a different font family:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.linspace(0, 10), np.linspace(0, 1), label='First plot \hphantom{Second} \#1')
ax.plot(np.linspace(0, 10), np.linspace(0, 2), label='Second plot \hphantom{First} \#2')
ax.legend(loc='best', title="My Awesome Legend Title")
```

[image: aligning legend labels with latex]