Change font of matplotlib colorbar and tick labels?
I'm having trouble setting the font of a plot I've made. I'm trying to use the font 'Arial Nova Light' which is installed on my system. I've tried multiple attempts to set the font family, both by giving the path of the file and using the system fonts, but I have been getting the following error.
findfont: Font family 'Arial Nova' not found.

This is made slightly more difficult by the fact that I don't have permission to view all directories on this machine. I've had some success using the .ttf file locally and setting parameters in the following way:
fpath = Path('Arial Nova.ttf')
ax.set_xlabel('position in span (m)', font=fpath)
ax.set_ylabel('temperature (°C)', font=fpath)

However, I'm struggling to find the way to set the font of the colorbar label and tick mark labels.
My code is as follows:
def plot(example_param1, example_param2):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"}, figsize=(12, 6))

    fpath = Path('Arial Nova.ttf')
    print(fpath.name)

    surf = ax.plot_trisurf(distances.flat, temperatures.flat, function(
        example_param1, 
        example_param2
    ).flat, cmap='coolwarm')
    fig.colorbar(surf, ax=ax, shrink=0.5, aspect=5, label='deviation (mm)')
    ax.view_init(elev=30, azim=160)
    ax.set_xlabel('position in span (m)', font=fpath)
    ax.set_ylabel('temperature (°C)', font=fpath)
    plt.show()

Is there a way to set the font of the color bar and tick mark labels without setting the font family and instead using a similar method to setting the font of the x and y labels above?
Many thanks

Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321670/how-to-change-fonts-in-matplotlib-python

Yes, as mentioned, I can't set by font family.

Try this,
cb=fig.colorbar(surf, ax=ax, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)  
    for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():    
            tick.set_fontproperties(fpath) 
    for tick in ax.get_yticklabels():
            tick.set_fontproperties(fpath) 
   for tick in ax.get_zticklabels():
            tick.set_fontproperties(fpath) 
    for l in cb.ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels():
                l.set_fontproperties(fpath)


cb.ax.set_ylabel('deviation (mm)',font=fpath)

Similiar problem: Python: how to change font in a colorbar?
