# Change Matplotlib's default font

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, default

I'm trying to change matplotlib's default font to Helvetica Neue. On my Mac with EPD/Canopy everything worked fine some time ago.

Trying to do the same on ubuntu now and it's not working.

This is what I did:

1. Installed Helvetica Neue

   ```
   $ fc-match 'Helvetica Neue':Light
   HelveticaNeue-Light.otf: "Helvetica Neue" "細體"
   ```
2. Converted the odt/dfont into ttf:

   ```
   fondu -show HelveticaNeue.dfont
   ```
3. changed matplotlibrc to

   ```
   $ cat ~/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc
   ...
   font.family: Helvetica Neue
   ```

   I also tried with:

   ```
   font.family: sans-serif
   font.sans-serif: Helvetica Neue
   ```
4. I removed the font cache

   ```
   rm ~/.config/matplotlib/fontList.cache
   ```

But none of these steps are working for me.

```
    $ python -c 'from  matplotlib import pyplot as plt; plt.plot(1); plt.savefig("/tmp/test.png")'
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.3.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1236: 
    UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['Helvetica Neue'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
```

(prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))

Version is 1.3.0

```
    $ python -c 'import matplotlib; print  matplotlib.__version__'
    1.3.0
```

I also tried moving the fonts to `~/.config/matplotlib/fonts/ttf` but it didn't work.

---

**EDIT:**
As suggested I tried selecting a specific font for a specific text.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager

path = '/home/<myusername>/.fonts/HelveticaNeue.ttf'

prop = font_manager.FontProperties(fname=path)
prop.set_weight = 'light'
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = prop.get_name()
mpl.rcParams['font.weight'] = 'light'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Text in a cool font', fontproperties=prop, size=40)
plt.savefig('/tmp/test2.png')
```

But it makes no difference.

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.3.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1236: 
UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['Helvetica Neue'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
```

However I seem to experience this problem only with this Helvetica/Helvetica Neue font.
      (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))

Comment: Before trying to change the default, have you been able to use the new font directly/explicitly? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18821968/1643946 shows one way to list the fonts that python/mpl has available, and you could try using `plt.text(1, 1, 'rattling', font_family="Helvetica Neue")`.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/16574948/1643946

Comment: Fair point. I've tried now with no success. Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Can you try this installing from the master branch?  There has been a bunch of work recently related to font-lookup.  It also looks like the font has non-ascii in the name, iirc there is a bug someplace upstream that makes that not work.

Comment: @tcaswell Tried with master ('1.4.x') and it's the same. Note that the same font (literally the same, I copied it across) works fine on my MacOS machine.

Comment: Please create an issue on github for this. It smells like a bug to me.

Comment: Maybe you also have to delete `fontList.cache`? That's what I had to do.

Answer (score 17):

This will not change your font permanently, but it's worth a try.

```
matplotlib.rc('font', family='sans-serif') 
matplotlib.rc('font', serif='Helvetica Neue') 
matplotlib.rc('text', usetex='false') 
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 22})
```

Comment: I think the problem is not with the default behaviour, but more with the fact that it's not recognising my Helvetica Neue font. I filed a bug on github.

Comment: I'm using the EPD python version (https://www.enthought.com/products/epd/) and Helvetica Neue is recognized there.

Comment: Great, thanks. On what OS? On my EPD (Canopy actually) for Mac it works too, but on Ubuntu it's not working.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Upload the fonts

```
sudo cp NotoSansKR-Regular.otf /usr/share/fonts/
```

Update the cache of font

```
sudo fc-cache -fv
```

You can check the font list

```
fc-list
```

Restart ipython, etc.
Check the font list

```
[f.name for f in matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.ttflist]
```

Take a your font name

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['font.family'] = 'Noto Sans Korean'
```

Draw

```
plt.title(u'한글 제목')
plt.xlabel(u'한글 축 이름')
plt.plot(range(5))
```

Comment: Looks good, but does not work: `[f.name for f in matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.ttflist]` gives `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'font_manager'`

Comment: Could you try this command ```import matplotlib.font_manager```

Comment: sometimes  `matplotlib.font_manager._rebuild()` is needed to use the new font

Comment: @Tobias when I try that, I get `AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.font_manager' has no attribute '_rebuild'
`

Answer (score 2):

Kim already introduced dynamic solution works perfectly, and here's two other ways doing the same in static.

First, you may put a line to rc file for matplotlib . Refer to [this page](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) for more information about locating the file and detailed settings.

```
font.family : NanumGothic
```

Second, if you are working with ipython, you can put some commands for font setting to a configuration file for the interactive shell. Find the file named ipython_config.py which usually located under ~/.ipython/somewhere. Then add two more lines to the list, c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines .

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [
    "import matplotlib as mpl",
    "mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'NanumGothic'"
]
```

Former always works whatever environment you run your shell script on as it loads the font when your script imports matplotlib .

Answer (score 1):

The font cache shows up in a different place for me (.cache/matplotlib/fontList.cache). And before I actually had three of them in different places somehow :/

maybe try searching for it in your home directory:

```
find ~/ -name fontList.cache -exec rm {} \;
```