# How to set matplotlib font for title, axes,

Tags: python, matplotlib

I don't know how to change the font, let's say to "times". My attempt does not work.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x     = np.array([0, 75, 150])
y     = np.array([0, 1, 3])
coeff = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)

xx = np.linspace(0, 150, 150)
yy = coeff[0] * xx**2 + coeff[1] * xx + coeff[2]

plt.title(unicode("Correction factor", "utf-8"),fontname="times")
plt.xlabel(unicode("Temperature in °C", "utf-8"))
plt.ylabel(unicode("fKorr", "utf-8"))
plt.plot(xx,yy)
plt.show()
```

EDIT: It works with "Times New Roman". Other programs I use know "times".

Comment: maybe this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461155/change-matplotlibs-default-font

Comment: what happens when you run the code? The syntax of line `unicode("Correction factor, "utf-8"),fontname="times")` is incorrect, it  should be `unicode("Correction factor", "utf-8"),fontname="times")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depended on the platform, the name of Times New Roman font can be different, for example in my current machine, `Mac OS`:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as fmg
for i, item in enumerate(fmg.findSystemFonts()):
    try:
        name=fmg.FontProperties(fname=item).get_name()
        if 'TIMES' in name.upper():
            print name, item, i
    except:
        pass

#Times New Roman /Library/Fonts/Times New Roman Italic.ttf 223
#Times New Roman /Library/Fonts/Times New Roman Bold Italic.ttf 232
#Times New Roman /Library/Fonts/Times New Roman Bold.ttf 336
#Times New Roman /Library/Fonts/Times New Roman.ttf 367
```

I think this solution may be safer: directly supply the path to the font file. `matplotlib.font_manager.findSystemFonts()` will list the paths to every file:

```
x     = np.array([0, 75, 150])
y     = np.array([0, 1, 3])
coeff = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)

xx = np.linspace(0, 150, 150)
yy = coeff[0] * xx**2 + coeff[1] * xx + coeff[2]

all_font = fmg.findSystemFonts()
fontprop = fmg.FontProperties(fname=all_font[223]) #you may have a different index
plt.title(unicode("Correction factor", "utf-8"), fontproperties=fontprop)
fontprop = fmg.FontProperties(fname=all_font[232])
plt.xlabel(unicode("Temperature in °C", "utf-8"), fontproperties=fontprop)
fontprop = fmg.FontProperties(fname=all_font[236])
plt.ylabel(unicode("fKorr", "utf-8"), fontproperties=fontprop)
plt.plot(xx,yy)
```

[image]