# How do I add a downloaded truetypefont to matplotlib.font_manager's ttflist?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

I have a fancy truetype font that I want my networkx node labels (Chinese characters) to be displayed in.

After

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
```

I use

```
print([f.name for f in fm.fontManager.ttflist])
```

to get the list of available fonts I can later use in

```
networkx.draw(myGraph, font_family = "someFontFromTheList").
```

This is how I draw the graph:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge("火", "水")
nx.draw(G, with_labels = True, font_family = "TakaoPGothic", node_size = 1600, font_size = 25, node_color = "lightblue")
plt.savefig("graph.png")
```

The "TakaoPGothic" font is the only one I found in the list that includes CJK characters. By using it, I get at least [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSKSg.png).

Now how do I use my own font at `/path/to/my/font.ttf`? I guess the way to go is to somehow add it to the above-mentioned fontlist of matplotlib?

Comment: Usually you just have to install the font in your operating system such that matplotlib can use it. The font list of matplotlib is generated from the font available on the system.

Comment: Interestingly, this doesn't seem to be the case. I have a whole CJK font family called "Noto CJK" preinstalled on my system and it doesn't show up in the font list of matplotlib.

Comment: Hard to tell from the outside. There are a lot of issues with fonts in matplotlib already. Often they are solved by clearing the fontcache. Possibly this is also dependent on the OS.

Comment: I'll read on how to clear the font cache then. Thanks! I'm on Xubuntu 16.04 btw.

Comment: For future reference: If you have additional information for your question, please [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50756477/edit). People tend not to read comments.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, solved the issue myself like this: [how to set up a custom font with custom path to matplotlib global font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668219/how-to-set-up-a-custom-font-with-custom-path-to-matplotlib-global-font)

The graph now looks like this:

[image: this].