# how to set the font label to Helvetica and redesigning the axis label text using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

in below simple matlotlib plot I  want set the Helvertica font for text and axis label ad need to control the width of the axis, axis values. Additionally i need to write axis labels little bit differently like 'time' in both the axis will be just below right corner of INSTITUTE and COMPANY respectively.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y=[2,3,4,5,4,6,8,10,23,10]
plt.xlabel('INSTITUTEtime')
plt.ylabel('COMPANYtime')
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It is `plt.show()`. What time are you talking about? in bottom right corner??

Comment: INSTITUTEtime in the x axis label should be written as  INSTITUTE then just below right corner of the word INSTITUTE, time should be written.

Comment: its not any system time its a word 'time'

Comment: @Karthik can it be done ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the snippet. I don't have **Helvetica** font. If you want that font you would want to download it and configure it in your `matplotlibrc` file. Please check
[Font Configuration](https://www.programmersought.com/article/42475460750/) for more details.
[image: graph]

- **xyconfig is used to extract elements from dictionary. Its called dictionary unpacking.
- `plt.text(10,-2,'time')` here x-coordinate is 10 , y-coordinate is -2. As we know your x-axis limit is 10 so i gave x as 10 and i gave -2 because you wanted that text in bottom-right corner below (0,0) co-ordinate i.e negative y-axis
- `plt.text(-0.50,22,'time',rotation=90)` here y-coordinate is 22 because your y-axis limit is 20 so to position it a little above ,i gave it 22 and x-coordinate is -0.5 because you want your text to be place behind your y-axis thus in negative y-axis.
- `rotation=90` is parameter to rotate your text. You can also use this in `xticks and yticks`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y=[2,3,4,5,4,6,8,10,23,10]

xyconfig = {'fontname':'serif','size':12}
plt.xlabel('INSTITUTE',**xyconfig)
plt.ylabel('COMPANY',**xyconfig)
plt.xticks(fontname='serif',size=8)
plt.yticks(fontname='serif',size=8)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.text(10,-2,'time')
plt.text(-0.50,22,'time',rotation=90)
plt.title("Institute vs Company Time")
plt.show()
```

Comment: but it doesnot satisfy Helvertica font

Comment: @geo I have mentioned the reason above..Read it once and go through that link

Comment: @geo please check this too https://stackoverflow.com/a/43647344/12870513

Comment: can you please tell me how you are setting plt.text(10,-2,'time')  and i need y axis time to be in horizontal like x-axis

Comment: Thanks....is it possible to change the size of the axis numbers

Comment: @geo here is set `size=8` you can change it to whatever you want