# matplotlib - mathtext italics not in desired font

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to get the italics font to match the font used for the rest of the axes labels but its not working as expected.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Garuda'
#solution is to change mathtext italics as suggested below
plt.rcParams['mathtext.it']= 'Garuda:italic'
plt.rcParams['mathtext.cal']= 'Garuda:italic'
plt.rcParams['mathtext.default'] = 'regular'
plt.rcParams["mathtext.fontset"] = 'custom'


x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_title('Plot $\it{ugly}$ $\it{italics}$', fontsize=14)
ax.text(-0.1, -0.5, 'nice italic font', style='italic', fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel('Nice$_2$ font', fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel('$Nice^+$ font', fontsize=14)
ax.tick_params(labelsize=12)
plt.show()
```

[image]

As it can be seen in the figure, the title has a mix between regular and italic fonts. How can I mix both types of font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the font you choose has an italic style, otherwise matplotlib will use a fallback font for that.

For example:

```
# this will change regular text in the figure
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Typewriter Revo'

# this is targeted to latex content
plt.rcParams['mathtext.it']= 'Typewriter Revo:italic'
plt.rcParams['mathtext.cal']= 'Typewriter Revo:italic'
plt.rcParams['mathtext.default'] = 'regular'
plt.rcParams["mathtext.fontset"] = 'custom'
```

[image: plot with custom font]

To be able to work with custom fonts I had to add them to matplotlib's list. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43647344/3247017) is a good solution for that problem.

Comment: solved with `plt.rcParams['mathtext.it']= 'Garuda:italic'` thank you very much