# Set matplotlib font by family name when there are multiple fonts with same name

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, fonts

How can I tell `matplotlib` to use a specific variant of a font when they both have the same name and characteristics?

For example, I can tell `matplotlib` to use Latin Modern Roman:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path

import matplotlib as mpl
import PyQt5
mpl.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Latin Modern Roman'
mpl.rcParams['font.weight'] = '400'
mpl.rcParams['font.style'] = 'normal'
mpl.rcParams['font.variant'] = 'normal'
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'custom'
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.default'] = 'it'
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.rm'] = 'Latin Modern Roman:normal'
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.it'] = 'Latin Modern Roman:italic'
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.bf'] = 'Latin Modern Roman:bold'

mpl.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 8
mpl.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 8
mpl.rcParams['axes.titlesize'] = 10
mpl.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 10

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
y = np.sin(x)

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3*(9/16)), dpi=300)
ax1 = fig1.gca()
ax1.plot(x, y, c='r', linewidth=1.0, zorder=20)
ax1.set_xlabel(r'$x\ label$')
ax1.set_ylabel(r'$y\ label$')
fig1.tight_layout(pad=0.15)
plt.show()
```

[image]

OK, that's nice. But what if I want to use a specific "substyle" of Latin Modern Roman? For example, on my system, when I list the available font entries having `name='Latin Modern Roman'` and `weight=400` and `style='normal'` and `variant='normal'` through:

```
fonts = mpl.font_manager.fontManager.ttflist
for f in fonts:
    if (f.name=='Latin Modern Roman'):
        if all([(f.style=='normal'),(f.weight==400),(f.style=='normal'),(f.variant=='normal')]):
            print(f.name)
            print(Path(f.fname).stem)
            print(f.fname)
            print('weight : %s'%str(f.weight))
            print('style : %s'%str(f.style))
            print('stretch : %s'%str(f.stretch))
            print('variant : %s'%str(f.variant))
            print('\n')
```

I get:

```
Latin Modern Roman
lmroman9-regular
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman9-regular.otf
weight : 400
style : normal
stretch : normal
variant : normal

...
...

Latin Modern Roman
lmroman10-regular
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf
weight : 400
style : normal
stretch : normal
variant : normal
```

So how would I tell `matplotlib` that I want to use `lmroman9-regular.otf` vs `lmroman10-regular.otf`? In `mpl.rcParams` I can only specify `font.family`,`font.weight`,`font.style` and `font.variant` so if the two `.otf` files have all the same values, how can I tell it to use one `.otf` rather than the other? There are actually differences between the fonts, for example:

[image]

I've tried referencing the `.otf` file directly with a `matplotlib.FontProperties` instance, then renaming it, then pointing to the new name like:

```
prop = mpl.font_manager.FontProperties(fname='/usr/share/fonts/opentype/lmodern/lmroman10-regular.otf')
prop.set_name('Latin Modern Roman Type 10')
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Latin Modern Roman Type 10'
```

but then I get `findfont: Font family ['Latin Modern Roman Type 10'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.` because `prop.get_name()` still (mysteriously) returns `Latin Modern Roman` and not `Latin Modern Roman Type 10`

How can I tell `matplotlib` that I want to use a one over the other?

It's possible to explicitly use `fontproperties` to point to a `font_manager.FontProperties()` instance in most `set_label` and `set_ticklabel` calls (like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7728665/15744300)), but I'm looking for a way to set this globally through `rcParams`.

Note: I would NOT like to use `LaTeX` rendering (`text.usetex`) in `matplotlib`.

System:

- Ubuntu-20.04 on WSL2 on Windows 10 Pro 19042
- Python 3.8.5 / [GCC 9.3.0] on linux
- matplotlib 3.4.1

Comment: have you tried setting `fontproperties=prop` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7728665/15744300)?

Comment: that doesn't work in math mode and also requires setting `fontproperties=prop` in every `set_label()` and `set_ticklabels()` call, which not convenient / maintainable. I'm looking for some way to set this globally through `rcParams`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a really good question. I will provide the way I found the solution to that specific problem. In order to reproduce it we first have to download the given fonts from [here](https://www.1001fonts.com/latin-modern-roman-font.html) (I downloaded the version 10 regular and the 17 version regular to see a clearer difference). Once installed we can check if our new font is found by `matplotlib`:

```py
from matplotlib import font_manager

font_manager.font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontext='otf') # Matplotlib associates with
# the .otf extension two more extensions viz. '.ttc' and '.ttf', as can be obtain over
# font_manager.get_fontext_synonyms('otf')
```

Once you have found your specified path to your `.otf` file, we can use the `font_manager` to make that specific version our selected font.

```py
# This will create an object which contains your file and give it a custom name
# Here is the idea of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668219/how-to-set-up-a-custom-font-with-custom-path-to-matplotlib-global-font
fe = font_manager.FontEntry(
    fname='C:\\Users\\<your_user_name>\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Fonts\\latin-modern-roman.mroman10-regular.otf',
    name='10erLatin')
font_manager.fontManager.ttflist.insert(0, fe) 
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = fe.name
```

Lets plot it so that we can later see whether it worked or not.

```py
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path

import matplotlib as mpl
# import PyQt5
# mpl.use('Qt5Agg') # I want to plot it inline ;)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = fe.name
mpl.rcParams['font.weight'] = '400'
mpl.rcParams['font.style'] = 'normal'
mpl.rcParams['font.variant'] = 'normal'
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'custom'
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.default'] = 'it'
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.rm'] = fe.name + ':normal'
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.it'] = fe.name + ':italic'
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.bf'] = fe.name + ':bold'

mpl.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 8
mpl.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 8
mpl.rcParams['axes.titlesize'] = 10
mpl.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 10

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
y = np.sin(x)

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3*(9/16)), dpi=300)
ax1 = fig1.gca()
ax1.plot(x, y, c='r', linewidth=1.0, zorder=20)
ax1.set_xlabel(r'$x\ label$')
ax1.set_ylabel(r'$y\ label$')
fig1.tight_layout(pad=0.15)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Lets change it up to the 17 version of the regular font.

```py
fe = font_manager.FontEntry(
    fname='C:\\Users\\<your_user_name>\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Fonts\\latin-modern-roman.mroman17-regular.otf',
    name='17erLatin')
font_manager.fontManager.ttflist.insert(0, fe) 
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = fe.name
```

Again, lets plot it (used the exact same code as above to create that plot, just executed the given code beforehand).

[image]

If my hindsight is not too bad, then the text changed globally. There are some other functions which might be useful to look at, however, they are really hidden in the [source  code](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/_modules/matplotlib/font_manager.html#FontEntry). Please let me know, if you run into problems.